# SQLAlchemy blank foreign key returning AttributeError

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to teach myself SQLAlchemy. I've come across a problem when working with tables that have relationships, but the foreign keys are sometimes blank. Here is the code:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
Base = declarative_base()
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

class Brewer(Base):
    __tablename__ = "brewer_table"
    brewer_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    brewery_name = Column(String)

class Style(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'style_table'
    style_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    style_name = Column(String)

class Beer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'beer_table'
    beer_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    beer_name = Column(String)
    beer_brewer = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("brewer_table.brewer_id"), nullable=True)
    beer_style = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("style_table.style_id"), nullable=True)
    brewer = relationship(Brewer)
    style = relationship(Style)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

light_beer = Style(style_name="light beer")
stout = Style(style_name="stout")
ipa = Style(style_name="india pale ale")
session.add_all([light_beer, stout, ipa])

budweiser = Brewer(brewery_name="Budweiser")
stone = Brewer(brewery_name="Stone")
session.add_all([budweiser, stone])

bud_light = Beer(beer_name="Bud Light", brewer=budweiser, style=light_beer)
stone_ipa = Beer(beer_name="Stone IPA", brewer=stone)
stone_americano = Beer(beer_name="Americano Stout", brewer=stone, style=ipa)
session.add_all([bud_light, stone_ipa, stone_americano])

session.commit()

query = session.query(Beer)
for beer in query:
    print(f"name: {beer.beer_name}, brewery: {beer.brewer.brewery_name}, style: {beer.style.style_name}")
```

As you can see, I do not have a style set for the second beer. When I run this, it throws the exception: AtributeError: 'NoneType' has no object attribute 'style_name'. If I include a style for the second beer, it runs fine.

I've tried testing for the value being none in several different ways, but I haven't been able to make that work.

I don't know if the relationship has to be more complex than what I have defined here, or if I'm fundamentally misunderstanding something about how to allow for a blank value in a foreign key. Any help anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The schema allows a `Beer`'s `Style` to be `None` - by setting `nullable=True`, so any code that works with `Beer` needs to be able to deal with this possibility.

One way to do this would be to test the style attribute inside the f-string, and produce some default output if it's `None` or an empty string.

```
for beer in query:
    print(f"name: {beer.beer_name}, brewery: {beer.brewer.brewery_name}, style: {beer.style.style_name if beer.style else 'MISSING'}")
```

produces

```
name: Bud Light, brewery: Budweiser, style: light beer
name: Stone IPA, brewery: Stone, style: MISSING
name: Americano Stout, brewery: Stone, style: india pale ale
```

This isn't very elegant, and it's easy to forget to add this check every time you want to print beer details.  If you are going to be using this f-string a lot, consider adding it to your beer model as its `__str__` method, like this:

```
class Beer(Base):

    ....

    def __str__(self):
        # This method is called whenever *str* is called on a Beer instance. 
        # Split long string in two and wrap in brackets so Python will
        # automatically concatenate them
        return (f"name: {self.beer_name}, brewery: {self.brewer.brewery_name}, "
                f"style: {self.style.style_name if self.style else 'MISSING'}")

for beer in query:
    print(beer)


name: Bud Light, brewery: Budweiser, style: light beer
name: Stone IPA, brewery: Stone, style: MISSING
name: Americano Stout, brewery: Stone, style: india pale ale
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was so close, but I'm not sure if I would have gotten there on my own.